# Inline element's absolute child position problem

Tags: html, css

I have an inline element with relative positioning and multiline content.
It also contains a child with an absolute positioning.
So i want to align this child to the right position of the parent element (a code snippet below).

But the lines have different length, and child element is aligned to a shorter one of the lines.

The first question is why this happening?
And the second one: is the any way to fix this problem?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: salmon;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="parent">
   Looooooooooooong Text here
   <div class="child"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: position:absolute on inline element doesn't play well. What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want child element to be right next to the text. I tried to solve this issue with flex, but failed

Answer (score 0):

It does not align to the shorter line, it aligns to the last line because it appears after that line in the HTML markup.

You can set the display mode of `.parent` to `display: inline-block;` in order to give it block boundaries, it makes more sense than positionning an element absoultely in relation to a normal inline layout.

Also, `.child` should be a `<span>` as well, `<div>` is a block element and it is not valid to put it inside a `<span>` which is an inline element<sup>[1]</sup>. The browser is forgiving and letting it work but you should avoid such a situation.

<sup>[1]</sup> In HTML5 the terms "block element" and "inline element" was replaced with another model, but the prencip still applies

```css
.container {
  max-width: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: salmon;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="parent">
    Looooooooooooong Text Here
   <span class="child"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution wont work, if word "Looooooooooooong" would be a little bit shorter.
If the parent element has "inline-block" display it fills all available width. But I want child to be right next to the text of the parent

Comment: `inline-block` does not take all available width by default, it takes the minimum width required for it's content. Try and see for yourself.

Comment: Tried it already
https://jsbin.com/lupehakori/
It `.parent` takes all width of the `.container`

Comment: I see. It doesn't take the entire width if the text is short enough to be kept in one line, but once the text has to be wrapped into the next line then it does not re-calculate the required width. Pretty frustrating. The only solution I managed to find is putting `width: min-content;` on the `.parent` element. It works but may come with the cost of breaking the text too much, depending on the length of the words.